# XML Signature Value mismatch issue

Tags: java, xml, cryptography, x509certificate, xml-signature

I have an issue with XML Signature value mismatch error. Full Scenario

- I generated a private 1024 bit key with OpenSSL.
- I generated the CSR with that private key and sent it to VISA, they have signed the document with their root CA certificate and sent me a signed certificate in the .pem format.
- I use the following java code to sign an XML document.

When i send the data back to VISA they verify the signature value and send an error of mismatch.

```
XMLSignatureFactory factory = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM", (Provider) Class.forName(providerName).newInstance());

DigestMethod digestMethod = factory.newDigestMethod(DigestMethod.SHA1, null);
factory.newTransform(Transform.ENVELOPED, (TransformParameterSpec) null);

Reference reference = factory.newReference("#" + paresId, digestMethod, null, null,null);
CanonicalizationMethod canonicalizationMethod = factory.newCanonicalizationMethod(CanonicalizationMethod.INCLUSIVE, (C14NMethodParameterSpec) null);
SignatureMethod signatureMethod = factory.newSignatureMethod(SignatureMethod.RSA_SHA1, null);
SignedInfo signedInfo = factory.newSignedInfo(canonicalizationMethod, signatureMethod, Collections.singletonList(reference));

KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
kpg.initialize(512);
KeyPair keyPair = kpg.generateKeyPair();
KeyInfoFactory keyInfoFactory = factory.getKeyInfoFactory();

KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS"); //PKC#7
keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePath), "dell12345".toCharArray());

KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry keyEntry =
    (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry("deskey", new KeyStore.PasswordProtection("dell12345".toCharArray()));

//PrivateKey m_objRequestSigningKey = (PrivateKey) obj_keyStore.getKey(str_alias, "password".toCharArray());


KeyStore.TrustedCertificateEntry rootEntry = (KeyStore.TrustedCertificateEntry) keyStore.getEntry("root", null);
X509Certificate rootCertificate = (X509Certificate) rootEntry.getTrustedCertificate();

KeyStore.TrustedCertificateEntry intermediateEntry = (KeyStore.TrustedCertificateEntry) keyStore.getEntry("intermediate", null);
X509Certificate intermediateCertificate = (X509Certificate) intermediateEntry.getTrustedCertificate();

KeyStore.TrustedCertificateEntry signEntry = (KeyStore.TrustedCertificateEntry) keyStore.getEntry("sign", null);
X509Certificate sigingCertificate = (X509Certificate) signEntry.getTrustedCertificate(); 

List<X509Certificate> x509 = new ArrayList<X509Certificate>();
x509.add(rootCertificate );
x509.add(intermediateCertificate );
x509.add(sigingCertificate );

X509Data x509Data = keyInfoFactory.newX509Data(x509);

List<X509Data> items = new ArrayList<X509Data>();
items.add(x509Data);


KeyInfo keyInfo = keyInfoFactory.newKeyInfo(items);

DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
Document doc =    dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(IOUtils.toInputStream(inputXml));

DOMSignContext dsc = new DOMSignContext(keyEntry.getPrivateKey(), doc.getDocumentElement());

XMLSignature signature = factory.newXMLSignature(signedInfo, keyInfo);
signature.sign(dsc);
```

Comment: `KeyPairGenerator` and the generated `KeyPair` are not used in your code and are not required since you already have the previously generated key in the keystore.

Comment: Also, if possible, add the full error message you get from the VISA.

Comment: Digital signature is invalid Signature not valid. SignatureValue mismatched.

Comment: KeyPairGenerator is not used in the code ,

Comment: You have called your private key "deskey" and you haven't stored any certificates with it?

Comment: I have added certificate chain and my private key in keystore and then get my private key with "deskey".

Comment: We were struggling for weeks until we detected that Java and .NET probably have different implementations of the standard. We were using C#.NETs SignedXml with RSA-SHA1 and inclusive C14. Our communication partner used Java. The problem is probably .NETs C14 implementation. We swapped to Mono's SignedXml implementation, and the signatures was no longer rejected.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, after a long time I am going to answer the question which I have posted 5 years back.

Actually, the problem was basically with the XML formatting, I removed the next line and carriage return characters from XML and send back to Visa and then my signature was match properly.

I don't know why they giving the error even I mentioned the CanonicalizationMethod properly.